# VBA Spin button with 10 digit min and max

Tags: excel, vba, button

I created a spin button on a user form however the min and max i'd like to set it to will not work when I change the properties of the spin button to a 10 digit value. I also tried to manually change it in the code but it would not allow me to run the code with the 10 digit min and max. It kept putting # after the 10 digit min and max then said error 424 when I tried to run it anyway. How can I change the properties of a spin button on a userform to 10-digit values?

Please try to explain the easiest way to do this as I'm not a pro coder or anything lol

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in userform:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    If TextBox1.Value > 9999999999# Then
        TextBox1.Value = 9999999999#
    ElseIf TextBox1.Value < 1000000000 Then
        TextBox1.Value = 1000000000
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Value = 1000000000
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
    If TextBox1.Value <> 1000000000 Then
        TextBox1.Value = TextBox1.Value - 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
    If TextBox1.Value <> 9999999999# Then
        TextBox1.Value = TextBox1.Value + 1
    End If
End Sub
```